# Yup domain name validation for punycode and cyrillic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

if you have troubles with Cyrillic domain name validation in yup this solution might help.

Our Yup validations will look like that

```
export const Domain = yup.object().noUnknown().shape({
  domain: yup.string().domain().required(),
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In this tutorial, we gonna use yup.addMethod which extends standard yup validations.

Now we should import modules and define regex.

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

const patterns = [
  domain: /^(?!:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,11}?$/,
  punycode: /^([A-Za-z0-9](?:(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]){0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9](?:(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]){0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)*)(\.?)$/,
  cyrillicDomain: /^((http|https):\/\/)?[a-zа-я0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-zа-я0-9]+)*\.[a-zа-я]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i,
];
```

Extend standard schema

```
yup.addMethod(yup.string, 'domain', function pattern(name, message = VALIDATION_ERRORS.domain) {
  const domainRules = [patterns.domain, patterns.punycode, patterns.cyrillicDomain];

  return this.test({
    message,
    test: value => (value === null || value === '' || value === undefined) || domainRules.some(regex => regex.test(value)),
  });
});
```

The next step is to add your validation in yup schema

```
export const Domain = yup.object().noUnknown().shape({
  domain: yup.string().domain().required(),
});
```

We are using this example in production and it works well.

Good luck!